# How to understand dynamic method creation

Tags: ruby

I saw the code:

```
class MyClass
  define_method :my_method do |my_arg|
    my_arg*3
  end
end 

obj = MyClass.new
obj.my_method(2)  # => 6
```

When we create `obj`, we have not yet called `define_method`, so `my_method` should not have been created. Then, why can we call `obj.my_method(2)` directly? In other words, is `define_method` executed at the time when `MyClass` is instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any method will be executed when it appears directly in the context that is read. There is no exception with method `define_method`, which defines a method. The method `define_method` is called (and hence the method `my_method` is defined) in line 2, which is before `obj` is created in line 7. And the defined method is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The method will be defined when the code defining the class is interpreted.

```
[6] pry(main)> class Foo
[6] pry(main)*   puts 'in Foo'
[6] pry(main)*   define_method :foo do |arg|
[6] pry(main)*     puts arg
[6] pry(main)*   end
[6] pry(main)* end
in Foo
=> #<Proc:0x007fcc1b176558@(pry):12 (lambda)>
[7] pry(main)> Foo.instance_methods(false)
=> [:foo]
```

Comment: So any code in class definition will be executed when the obj is created?

Comment: Yes - that's my understanding. If you're interested in metaprogramming, I'd recommend reading [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1364181853&sr=8-1&keywords=ruby+metaprogramming).

Comment: No they aren't. They are executed before `obj` is created. They are executed when they are read.